# In swift, using timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, NSDate is not identical to NSTimeInterval error

Tags: swift, datetime

I've two NSDates, one stamped by the devise, and the other entered by the user. I'd like to see if there is a difference between the two, and researched the following code, but I get an error message that NSDate is not identical to NSTimeInterval.

```
    let compareResult = recordDateTimeEntered!.compare(recordDateTimeEntered!)
    let timeFromEnteredtoStampedDates = recordDateTimeStamped.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate(recordDateTimeEntered)    // error: NSDate -> _ is not identical to NSTimeInterval
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare two dates for equality, you can use the `==` operator in Swift (or the `isEqualToDate:` method in Objective-C). You can alternatively check that the `timeIntervalSinceDate:` between two dates is less than an acceptable threshold, to determine if two dates are *roughly* equal.